# Uninstalling application built from source

Tags: software-center, uninstall, install-from-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

I know that Ubuntu has come a long way in helping new users to get used to their linux system..and making things as easy as possible. One most important aspect is installing and uninstalling applications in ubuntu. Thanks to Ubuntu Software Center it is a breeze!

However I noticed that when I compiled and installed a game from its source (battleship), it does not appear under the history tab in the Ubuntu Software Center. And also you cannot uninstall it through the software center but have to resort to the command line to do this. I do not mind doing it however I am sure some other users might not be comfortable with this.

Is this a bug?