# Removing software compiled and from source?

Tags: installation, source, make

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If i build a package from source. How can i uninstall or remove completely in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely-in-ub)

I downloaded the source and compiled ruby 1.9.2dev but getting lots of issues when i try to run rails on this version, i want to start clean again is there simple way to remove all files installed by "make install" or do i need to find and remove all manual?