# how to upgrade to latest python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update ubuntu’s python with latest version from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103772/how-to-update-ubuntus-python-with-latest-version-from-source)

I am using ubuntu 11.04. by default, there's a python already installed, it is version 2.7.1+

I know the latest one is 2.7.3.  when I try to upgrade it.

sudo apt-get install python2.7

I told me the latest one already installed.  is there a way I can remove what I have and reinstall the latest python?

Comment: See  http://askubuntu.com/a/104054/2018

Comment: thank you so much. I guess it cannot be done, at least not as easy as I thought.

Comment: My interpretation of that thread is: If you really need it, it can be done. If it's just for having the latest and greatest version, don't bother. Compiling from sources is not too difficult, but you'll definitely will run into a few error messages that need solving. Compiling from sources is not a rocket science.