# How to remove software installed from source, where "make" was not used?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I download this package and following the instructions on the website i untared its package in /usr/local/share and used ./install command to install it.

now I need to remove it. Is there anyway to do that ? If it needs them I still have the installation files.

[this](http://www.nsnam.com/2012/04/installing-ns-235-in-ubuntu-1204-lts.html) is the website

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: i don't think their the same, my package des not have any make files so i can't use 'make unistall'. it jus says:  make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'

Comment: Did the source package not come with an unistall script?

Comment: no it apears it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no uninstall option you need to manually remove the files.

Most (if not all) of the files will be installed inside a directory (from the readme I would assume it is called `ns-allinone-2.35`) at the path you ran ./install. Simply use a `rm -rf` to remove that directory and it will be gone.

Now for 1 extra step: during installion either the installer added some links to `~./bashrc` or you edited them in yourself. So do a (backup at the 2nd command):

```
cd ~
cp  .bashrc .bashrc_old
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and have a look for anything related to `ns-allinone-2.35` and remove it. Be careful; if you mess up it might be problematic. After editing you need to parse the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is delete the `ns-allinone-2.35` directory.

When you ran `install` from within that directory, it installed everything into the same directory.

The installer doesn't appear to make any changes to your `./bashrc` file on it's own, but if you added any of the changes they recommend, then, of course, you will also need to undo those changes.