# How to remove files created by sudo make install (even though the process failed due to lack of space)

Tags: software-uninstall

I was installing `llvm` using `sudo make install` but due to space constraints it was not completed and failed, but it has created so many heavy files in my machine so that now I am running out of space.

Can someone tell me how to delete files that were created during the incomplete installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo make uninstall`. This target is usually configured in `make` installations.

Comment: actually now I have deleted that directory from where I did make install

Comment: Try doing any build configurations you need to do, but instead of doing `make`, run `sudo make uninstall`. If it complains that it can't find an install manifest, re-build it, re-install it (it should overwrite existing files), and then run the uninstall target.