# How can I uninstall python3.5.0 installed from source code?

Tags: source-code, software-uninstall

I installed python 3.5.0 from the source code available at python.org. How can I remove that installed package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-ie-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-lin)

You can do :

1. `make clean` removes any intermediate or output files from your source / build tree
2. If you can, running `make uninstall` will work.
3. The last option is you have to manually uninstall it. Running `make -n install`

**Note** : You must `cd` the file location where you `make install`

Comment: `make clean && make distclean` are also solution for uninstalling from source =)

Comment: @NikolayNikolov yes because this is the way he do it

Comment: Yes, you are right @BeGood :)

Comment: I ran the above commands and I think they worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did not work for python 3.8 and Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score -2):

I think this will work. Try this.

```
pip uninstall python==3.5.0
```

However, if python comes with dependencies, do not uninstall them.

Comment: This won't work. `pip` is responsible for Python packages, not for Python itself.

Answer (score -6):

```
locate python3.5 | xargs sudo rm -rf $1
```

Comment: -1 No, don't do this; it's **dangerous** because it deletes other files of that name that don't belong to the Python installation. There's not even a guarantee that it will delete all files that *do* belong to it.