# How to uninstall python 3.8 from Ubuntu after deleting the folder Python-3.8.0 using "rm -rf"?

Tags: python3

I have a VM with Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. It has by default Python 3.5.2

And, I have installed Python 3.8 following the following procedure:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.8.0
cd Python-3.8.0
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

As I will install miniconda and I want to avoid any conflicts, I would like to know how to uninstall it.

So far I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge python3.8        AND

sudo apt-get --purge remove python3.8
```

And finally I have just deleted the folder which contained it, by mistake :(

But I still have it. Check the image.

[image]

Is it possible to uninstall it? Will I have any problems in the future?

Thank you

Comment: Can you restore the source/build directory and try `make uninstall` or the other things mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/701375/367990)? - Also for the next time, the easiest way to get custom Python versions on Ubuntu (LTS releases) is using the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) in my opinion.

Comment: apt will only remove packages. You used 'make altinstall' so try above comment, if it doesn't work then you'll need to manually remove  all the installed files that make altinstall installed.

Comment: @ByteCommander I cannot find my Trash. I do not have a `/home/ubu-admin/.local/share/Trash`

Comment: You can probably also just download and extract the archive once more and run your same configure command again, then try to `sudo make uninstall` or the other ways mentioned in the link, I guess.

Comment: So, do you mean to install twice Python 3.8?

Comment: @ByteCommander It worked! I used METHOD 2 of this web page: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li`

Answer (score 9):

I got python3.8 when I did `apt-get update` on ubuntu 20.

These two steps removed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get -y purge python3.8
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

In Dockerfile you have to remove sudo.

```
apt-get -y purge python3.8
apt-get -y autoremove
```

Comment: This removed python along with a lot of other things in ubuntu. Recommend not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the package using the same procedure:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.8.0
cd Python-3.8.0
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

And added these lines:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
sudo make altinstall
```

Then I used METHOD 2 of this webpage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li

But I made some modifications.

```
sudo apt -y install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

I said "no" to ALL the questions.
And then I used this command:

```
dpkg -r python
```

FINAL RESULT

[image]

I deleted the Python3.8 folder:

```
sudo rm -rf Python-3.8.0
```