# how to remove python 3.4.4 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I installed python 3.4.4 in ubuntu 14.04, but I want to remove it.

when I open terminal and type `python3.4 -V` then the output is the following.

> Python 3.4.4

when I installed, I referenced this web-site
["i referenced this website"](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/#)

I want to remove python 3.4.4 how to do?
I am linux newbie please help me.

when i enter /usr/src/Python-3.4.4 directory and type `make uninstall` or `sudo make uninstall` then output message is that

> make *** no rule to make target uninstall'. stop

I think that method isn't working.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I referenced this web-site
http://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: oh thank you. Could I ask one more? now in /usr/src/ directory, I have Python-3.4.4.tgz file and Python-3.4.4 directory.
According to solution that you suggested, I enter Python-3.4.4 directory and need to type sudo apt-get uninstall, right??

Comment: Ah, never mind. Python's Makefile doesn't have an `uninstall` option. You'll have to run `make -n altinstall`, see which files were installed and delete them manually.

Comment: should I have to work in /usr/src/Python-3.4.4/ directory??

Comment: Yes, run `make -n altinstall` in `/usr/src/Python-3.4.4/`. You will see a list of commands and paths. Delete all the paths that mention `python3.4`.

Comment: can you teach me a little more? so many commands and paths are shown. but I don't know how remove them. I want to show you `make -n altinstall` output. do you know how to upload file? I hope i will be given how to do through some examples..

Comment: **Make sure you never accidentally remove the preinstalled Python 3 version! many tools like e.g. most package managers will not work any more if you remove that.** (Just a warning to be careful when it comes to removing Pythons *before* it's too late. I already advised far too many people to reinstall their system because of that in the last weeks. :-/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `make -n altinstall` and doing a bit of processing<sup>1</sup>, the relevant paths are:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.4
/usr/local/include/python3.4
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.4
/usr/local/lib/python3.4
/usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.4
```

Some of these maybe temporary - only used during installation and deleted after finishing it. So, you might not find some of these. Delete the rest.

---

<sup>1</sup> I just ran:

```
make -n altinstall | grep -v rm | grep -Po '/usr/local[^[:space:]]*?python3.4' | sort -u
```

This filters out `rm` commands, and then prints only the paths in `/usr/local` (the default location picked by `./configure`) that end in `python3.4` and removes duplicated entries.