# Uninstall VLC , installed using Source file

Tags: command-line, apt, vlc, software-sources, software-uninstall

I installed `vlc` using `tar.xz` file, now I want to remove it but as I have deleted the source directory from which it was installed, I am unable to uninstall it.

I have tried these commands:

```
apt-get remove vlc
apt-get remove vlc-nox
apt-get remove vlc-data
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge vlc
```

without success

Comment: Close Voters: The Duplicate mentioned in the close vote has an accepted answer that involves runing `make uninstall` from the source tree. The OP has deleted this source so IMHO this is not an exact Duplicate...

Comment: @andrew.46 the OP can download the same sources again and run `make uninstall`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

1. Download the sources again (preferably with exactly the same version).
2. Install it from sources again (overwriting the old install)
3. Then follow the answer to this question mentioned in the comments: [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: If you downvote please give a reason to educate us. :)