# How to uninstall OpenBLAS on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04

I installed and compiled OpenBLAS on Ubuntu 14.04 with following instructions:

```
sudo git clone git://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS
cd OpenBLAS
sudo apt-get install gfortran
sudo make FC=gfortran
sudo make install
```

Now I want to uninstall it. How? I checked on the internet but with no result. Help, please. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Within the source directory for OpenBLAS you may be able to make an uninstall file using the same Makefile that came with OpenBLAS:

> sudo make unistall

And then you would just run that `uninstall`.

This is somewhat similar to the answers here: [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: I tried it at first place, it didn't work.