# Why package installed by compiling its source code does not appear in dpkg -l output?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, source-packages

I'm seeing a potentially problematic issues here when I use the command line:

```
dpkg -l | grep macchanger
```

**It would** list macchanger and the version with no problems.

I recently uninstalled this buggy version I had via:

```
apt-get remove macchanger
```

Then reinstalled it but I manually compiled and installed it from sources from GitHub.  Now when I use:

```
dpkg -l | grep macchanger
```

I get absolutely nothing and the issue is that I want to be able to keep track of the package.

Comment: I think `checkinstall` is what you are looking for... http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely

Comment: A better command to use would be `dpkg -l *macchanger*`.

Answer (score 1):

**Debian Package Management System** only keeps track of packages installed by `dpkg` and other utilities based on it. Installing from source code (Compiling the source and installing produced files) is another way to install packages. This means that packages installed by compiling their source code isn't listed in `dpkg -l` and cannot be removed using `dpkg -r`. The only way to remove a package installed by compiling it source is issuing this command in compile directory of it:

```
make uninstall
```

Please note that some source codes don'y support `make uninstall`.

In some cases you can download `.deb` of that version and installing by `dpkg -i` command. This way need high knowledge of package management in Ubuntu because a mistake cause broken `dpkg` database.