# Uninstalling wicd from source?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, wicd

I wanted to hack around with wicd so I went ahead, downloaded a tarball, removed the wicd packages on my system, and installed from source (with the no gnome extensions flag), but now I'm having issues reverting to the wicd package.

The installed-from-source version works OK, except for the fact that every time I restart my computer it prompts me to enter my password (which never happened with the package version). I tried using

```
sudo apt-get install -d wicd...andrandomrependencies
```

to download the wicd package, and then running the source's `uninstall.sh`, but I got the following error.

```
There does not appear to be an installation log present, most
likely because you did not install Wicd from this directory.
```

That "most likely reason" is untrue, but even if I try installing wicd from source and immediately running `uninstall.sh`, I still get the error.

Worse still, the source version seems to take precedence over the package version- even with the wicd package installed now, I'm still getting that prompt on bootup to elevate the wicd daemon's privileges.

Do you know of any ways to properly uninstall wicd?

Comment: See [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: @steeldriver the problem is that the uninstall script doesn't work

Comment: Probably because (un)installing from a Debian source package is not the same as installing from a generic source tarball. Do you still have the source that you *originally* installed from? or the original tarball that you could unpack / configure and then look for an uninstall Makefile target (rather than a standalone shell script)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, in fact that's what I've been trying to install from