# uninstall R from home directory

Tags: uninstall, r

I have R installed at 2 places in my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) 
`usr/bin/R` and `/home/amit/bin/R`.
I want to remove the older version from `home/amit/bin/R`and use the new version installed in `usr/bin/R`.
I tried using the `sudo apt-get remove /home/amit/bin/R` but it returns `E: Unable to locate package /home/amit/bin`.

Kindly help.

Comment: you likely didn't use `apt-get` to install it in your home dir, so **how did you install it**? if you compiled R from source, you can use `make uninstall` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: please, at least tell us that how did you install them at fist place

Comment: I tried make uninstall and it worked....thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the older version of R from here `https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/`
and set up using `./configure --prefix=/home/amit/`.
I wanted to use a tool which can be run on an older version of R.