# Unable to start Ubuntu after installing Gedit dependencies

Tags: compiling, software-sources, xserver, init, checkinstall

While I was trying to build [Gedit](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit) on Ubuntu 16.04, I followed the prerequisite dependencies and installed them religiously. I noticed that I lost my terminal color, and the preinstalled gedit theme and before that pychess stopped working because of missing dependencies. So I restarted the machine. 
Now when I try to load, after i pass the Grub menu, the screen start flickering and nothing happens. I definitely broke something with the GTK packages and all the dependencies.

First of all, I didn't follow the rule number one:  <strike>Never talk about the fight club</strike>. Always backup your system. 
That being said, I am able to access my machine in init mode 3.
So before doing something stupid, I came to have some advice and also to seek help ...

The idea [I come up with](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely) is to go inside all the sources files and do a
   `sudo checkinstall` followed with a `sudo dpkg -r <package>`.
What is the best solution to restore the system without reinstalling everything?
And how in the future can I avoid such situation when I need to install software from the source?
(Is there a good tutorial to explain the compiling process and the good reflexes to have?)

Comment: Ubuntu depends on GTK and 16.04 is build and tested with a specific version of GTK. What you did may have introduced a different version of GTK that has compatibility issues with the rest of the Ubutn 16.04. Probably need to remove the gtk you build and install the one back from the repo.

Comment: How can I have the list of the default package once I remove the package installed from the source ?

Comment: good question. One thing you might be able to do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall`. Hope that works.

Comment: I am actually unable to to checkinstall the dependencies, plus I compiled a program using meson ...

Comment: Try removing anything you have installed, and force the installation of ubuntu-desktop as described in my earlier comment.

Comment: How can I find where all the packages have been installed, I posted a more detailed question explaining the log I checked  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064805/how-to-purge-everything-related-to-the-gui)

Comment: You need to clarify how you built and installed the software you described. Did you build the deb packages and did a `dpkg -i` or did you use `make install` or something else.