# How to purge everything related to the GUI

Tags: uninstall, lightdm, gui, xserver

How to reinstall broken Ubuntu (16.04) GUI and purging all the related libraries, and  the packages installed from the sources related to the GUI ?

Firstly I tried to install the latest version at that time [gedit 3.28.1](https://download.gnome.org/sources/gedit/3.28/), and I followed [this walkthrough](http://installfights.blogspot.com/2016/08/install-lastest-gedit-version-3202-on.html).
(I just realized that it wasn't the good version).

#### list of the installed packages

- [Gspell](https://github.com/GNOME/gspell.git)
- [Gtk 3.21.4](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.21/gtk+-3.21.4.tar.xz)
- [Glib 2.49.4](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.49/glib-2.49.4.tar.xz)
- [Gtk-sourceview 3.21.3](http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnome.org/sources/gtksourceview/3.21/gtksourceview-3.21.3.tar.xz)

I was able to retrieve the "dpkg log" for the 3.28.1 in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2Z2wXE8Y).
At the same time, I noticed that I can't run a python program ([pychess](http://www.pychess.org/)),  because of a missing dependencie error.
After that I went for the 2.27.4 version of [Gedit](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit).

#### list of the installed packages and their dependencies for gedit 2.27.4

1. [Gspell 1.8.2](https://github.com/GNOME/gspell)
2. Glib 2.49.4
3. [Gtk+-3.22.30](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html)

   - [at-spi2-atk-2.26.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/at-spi2-atk.html)

     - [atk-2.28.1](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/atk/2.28/atk-2.28.1.tar.xz)
     - [at-spi2-core-2.28.0](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/at-spi2-core.html)
   - [gdk-pixbuf-2.36.12](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gdk-pixbuf.html)

     - [glib-2.56.1](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/glib2.html)

The dpkg log for this session is in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Tp3gfRc3).

I ended loosing my terminal colors (all white with light foreground text), and  when I restarted the machine, the Ubuntu splash screen and a black screen kept alternating and flickering 
I can however access the machine via a tty, or by booting in init3 mode.
I reinstalled Ubuntu-desktop and Unity like this, but nothing changed

> sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
>   sudo apt remove unity
>   sudo apt autoremove
>   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
>   sudo apt install unity

I was also unable  to `sudo apt checkinstall` in the sources directories because of a missing library.
I also tried to boot in xfailsafe mode, It raised a `Fatal server error: no screens found(EE)`.
Here is a copy of the [log](https://pastebin.com/s3GtYmUn).

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

`lsb_release -a`

> LSB Version:  core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>   Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
>   Release:  16.04
>   Codename: xenial

`uname -a`

> Linux neo-box 4.7.0.intel.r5.0 #1 SMP Sun Jun 3 18:17:18 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Is it possible to revert to the state previous to all this?

Comment: If I upgrade to another version will this fix the problem ?

Comment: Since you say you installed software from source, upgrading Ubuntu seems unlikely to solve the problem (and might make the problem worse).

Comment: Any  clue how I can fix this ?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify *exactly* what you did, what changes you made to your system configs, what additional packages you installed, and whatever partial fixes you may have tried. Reinstalling the GUI is not very difficult...unless you have added new sources, wrong-version packages, or non-packaged software. We need to know details about all of those.

Comment: If you want the most recent version of applications, please install the most recent version of Ubuntu. The version 18.04 includes [Gedit 3.28.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gedit). See also [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/250300)