# Is there a log file equivalent to manifest.txt

Tags: uninstall, software-sources, log

I am trying to revert everything installed while compiling dependencies.
I looked inside [`/var/log/dpkg`](https://pastebin.com/2Z2wXE8Y) but couldn't find the location of the installed libraries.
Which log can I look into to remove/revert everything installed from the sources?

Comment: Probably the only log file you can look at is your shell's history.

Comment: I did but it only shows the command I entered. It could help me if I can see their output.

Comment: If you didn't save the output and have closed the terminal in which you ran them, those are lost.

Comment: OK I see. Can you help me figure out a solution to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064805/how-to-purge-everything-related-to-the-gui) I put myself into ?

Comment: That mess is probably not worth figuring out - reinstalling Ubuntu would be less painful.

Comment: By carefully reading `/var/log/apt/*` you can get the name of the packages you installed. Packages should be removed, not the library files. `sudo apt autoremove` will remove all packages not required by a currently installed packge, and is probably your safest choice.

Comment: I'll give It a try before resigning myself to reinstall and loose everything.Thanks! Since I have the time stamps of the installed packages, that can help I guess.