# E: Unable to locate package HexChat

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Hexchat and remove it completely so I can install it again, because it's broken.

And any ”purge remove or autoremove” does not uninstall it.
Some ”config files” are not deleted. Every time I reinstall it, it looks the same (broken).

I tried to use answers from similar questions: ”unable to locate package” but i do not understand anything, I am a beginner.Ubuntu 21.04

I used `apt search HexChat` and i get many lines with the Hirsute:

```
hexchat/hirsute-updates,now 2.1....
hexchat-common/hirsute-updates,hirsute-updates,now 2.14...
```

What can i do next? I will provide answers with the commands that someone will suggest in Terminal. I need step by step guidance.

`sudo apt-get --purge remove` is not working either.
(Hexchat is broken, and if I reinstall it, is still broken)

```
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[ca]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[cs]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[da]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[de]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[el]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[en_GB]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[es]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[et]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[eu]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[fi]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[fr]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[gl]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[id]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[it]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[ja_JP]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[lt]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[lv]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[nb]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[pl]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[pt]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[pt_BR]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[ru]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[sl]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[sq]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[sv]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[tr]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name[zh_CN]=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Name=HexChat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Exec=hexchat --existing %U
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Icon=hexchat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:StartupWMClass=Hexchat
/usr/share/applications/io.github.Hexchat.desktop:Exec=hexchat --no-auto --no-plugins
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/irc=io.github.Hexchat.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/ircs=io.github.Hexchat.desktop;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129599/discussion-on-question-by-lucianbuntu-e-unable-to-locate-package-hexchat).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to uninstall package with error "Unable to locate package"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078404/unable-to-uninstall-package-with-error-unable-to-locate-package) From the accept4ed answer: *Package names in Ubuntu are case sensitive and pieces of package names are not interpreted by apt to be exact package names.*

Comment: I want to remove this HexChat program because is broken and reinstall it clean.
All the things i have tried give the same result. Program is still there, in the same broken state/form.