# For which Ubuntu versions is clangd suitable?

Tags: 18.04, versions, clang

Trying to install a clangd on Ubuntu18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install clangd
```

I get an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package clangd
```

On another Ubuntu 18.04, everything works and the installation goes through, both systems have just been installed

The difference in Ubuntu is only in the kernel:

```
uname -a
```

Ubuntu with error: `Linux ubuntuName1 5.4.0-84-generic #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 2 23:36:48 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Ubuntu without error: `Linux ubuntuName2 5.4.0-117-generic #132~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 2 23:36:48 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Where can I find out the versions on which clangd is installed without problems? And what is the difference between 5.4.0-117 and 5.4.0-84 what is the error between them

I didn't find any information on the official websites

UPD:

On ubuntu with kernel 5.4.0-117-generic, I was able to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install clangd
```

At the same time, Ubuntu lang version `11.0.1-2~18.04.sav0 was installed`
On Ubuntu 5.4.0-84 I was only able to execute

```
sudo apt-get install clangd-10
```

The universe is enabled on both machines

Why does the `sudo apt-get install clangd` not work on both systems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clangd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all and you'll see it's found in *universe* , do you have it enabled on both?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: This question is easily answered yourself if you browse http://packages.ubuntu.com: The package named `clangd` was added to the Ubuntu repositories *after* 18.04. If `clangd` installs on a stock 18.04 system, then *it's not really stock* and somebody has either downloaded the .deb or changed the sources.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I understand that in Ubuntu, where everything was installed, they still made changes without warning me. I will close the question so as not to confuse other users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to uninstall package with error "Unable to locate package"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078404/unable-to-uninstall-package-with-error-unable-to-locate-package)