# uninstall program compiled with make

Tags: make, configure

I'm trying to understand somethings about ***make*** command, and even if I've read the manual I still have some doubts about its usage. In particular, if I install a program (consisting in many packages) using the "classic" sequence of command on terminal, that is:

***./configure -prefix /usr/bin/my_program***   (here I refer to a configuration file usually provided with some softwares)

***make***

***sudo make install***

what it the inverse operation to unistall that program? It's enough to erase the whole directory choose before? (for example with sudo rm -r /usr/bin/my_program).

Thanks to anyone so kind to explain it to me

Comment: Maybe... maybe not. See [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: I'l prefer to use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ANY Makefile, do a `cat Makefile` and look at the very end of the listing. There you'll find what options `make` will understand (for that particular Makefile).

Look at the following code snippet... and look for "option:"... and in this example, we can see "all:" and "modules:" and etc... all the way down to "uninstall:"... and even a few more after that.

This typically means (in this case example), following your initial `make` command, and `sudo make install` to build and install the code, you can use `sudo make uninstall` to remove the installed code.

```
all: modules

modules:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(shell pwd)  modules
    @echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "Visit https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au for support/reporting issues"
    @echo "or check for newer versions (branches) of these drivers.                   "
    @echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
strip:
    $(CROSS_COMPILE)strip $(MODULE_NAME).ko --strip-unneeded

install:
    install -p -m 644 $(MODULE_NAME).ko  $(MODDESTDIR)
    /sbin/depmod -a ${KVER}

uninstall:
    rm -f $(MODDESTDIR)/$(MODULE_NAME).ko
    /sbin/depmod -a ${KVER}

backup_rtlwifi:
    @echo "Making backup rtlwifi drivers"
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(STAGINGMODDIR)/rtl*))
    @tar cPf $(wildcard $(STAGINGMODDIR))/backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar $(wildcard $(STAGINGMODDIR)/rtl*)
    @rm -rf $(wildcard $(STAGINGMODDIR)/rtl*)
endif
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(MODDESTDIR)realtek))
    @tar cPf $(MODDESTDIR)backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar $(MODDESTDIR)realtek
    @rm -fr $(MODDESTDIR)realtek
endif
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(MODDESTDIR)rtl*))
    @tar cPf $(MODDESTDIR)../backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar $(wildcard $(MODDESTDIR)rtl*)
    @rm -fr $(wildcard $(MODDESTDIR)rtl*)
endif
    @/sbin/depmod -a ${KVER}
    @echo "Please reboot your system"

restore_rtlwifi:
    @echo "Restoring backups"
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(STAGINGMODDIR)/backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar))
    @tar xPf $(STAGINGMODDIR)/backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar
    @rm $(STAGINGMODDIR)/backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar
endif
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(MODDESTDIR)backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar))
    @tar xPf $(MODDESTDIR)backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar
    @rm $(MODDESTDIR)backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar
endif
ifneq (,$(wildcard $(MODDESTDIR)../backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar))
    @tar xPf $(MODDESTDIR)../backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar
    @rm $(MODDESTDIR)../backup_rtlwifi_driver.tar
endif
    @/sbin/depmod -a ${KVER}
    @echo "Please reboot your system"

config_r:
    @echo "make config"
    /bin/bash script/Configure script/config.in

DRIVER_VERSION = $(shell grep "\#define DRIVERVERSION" include/rtw_version.h | awk '{print $$3}' | tr -d v\")

dkms_install:
    mkdir -p /usr/src/8812au-$(DRIVER_VERSION)
    cp -r * /usr/src/8812au-$(DRIVER_VERSION)
    dkms add -m 8812au -v $(DRIVER_VERSION)
    dkms build -m 8812au -v $(DRIVER_VERSION)
    dkms install -m 8812au -v $(DRIVER_VERSION)
    dkms status

dkms_remove:
    dkms remove 8812au/$(DRIVER_VERSION) --all
    rm -rf /usr/src/8812au-$(DRIVER_VERSION)

.PHONY: modules clean

clean:
    #$(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(shell pwd) clean
    cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
    cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
    cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
    cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd core ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
    cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *.o.d
    cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
    rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
    rm -fr .tmp_versions
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the makefile for answers.

`make` is great, but it's not magical. The `make` application can only do what it's instructed to do (like any application). Those instructions are in the makefile.

If there are 'install' instructions in the makefile, then `sudo make install` will work, otherwise it will fail.

Similarly, `make` needs 'uninstall' instructions for `sudo make uninstall` to work.

Comment: `sudo` must be used for the `make install` and `make uninstall`.

Comment: @heynnema good catch! edited.