# How to uninstall a package which is installed in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, uninstall, vim

I had installed VIM but it has been messed up and breaking up due to some plugins. So I removed it with: `sudo apt-get remove vim` . But there is still `vim` command available. I also tried `sudo apt-get purge vim` & `sudo apt-get remove vim-*`.

Below output for more information: 
`$whereis vim` 
`vim: /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/share/vim`

How can I uninstall them?

I have one more question: Can we know which package is responsible for the installation of a particular binary file? Is there any reverse-search for binary files?

System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (focal)

Comment: Packages don't install to `/usr/local`. That was probably installed from source. Your secondary question is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/a/482/158442

Comment: See also [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/share/vim` will show which package (if any) provides `/usr/share/vim`.