# How can I alter ~/.profile for RStudio

Tags: 20.04, rstudio

I installed the previous version of R (4.0.5) and redirected RStudio according to the RStudio Support site [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop). However, I would now like to go back to the repository version (R 4.1.0), which is on my system at /usr/bin/R. After running `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R` to go back, the result of `which R` still outputs '/usr/local/bin/R' so I cannot open RStudio from the Desktop Applications Menu. When I try, it's looking for an R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) even though I did build with the `--enable-R-shlib` option. If I open RStudio from the terminal, it opens fine with R 4.1.0

The support page says I need to change ~/.profile to be able to open RStudio from the Application Menu but I don't know how or where to change this. Is someone able to help with this? I would consider myself in the upper-beginner class of Linux user (I'm on Ubuntu 20.04).

I tried removing RStudio and the ~/.local/share/rstudio preferences and reinstalling but still have the same issue.

Thanks in advance,
Jeremy

Comment: Thanks @user68186, that's a start. The ~/.profile file currently has only if/then statements (if-then-fi) so do you (or someone else) know how I can write the `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R` in an appropriate form?

Comment: Let me write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Make a backup of your `.profile`

Open a terminal and use the `cp` command as follows:

```
cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.bak
```

#### Edit the `.profile` file

Open the `.profile` file in a text editor. The last few lines may look like this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Add a new line at the end of the last line and copy the command:

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R
```

Now the end of the file should look something like this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R
```

Save the files and close the text file editor.

Log out and log back in so that the changes take effect.

Open RStudio and verify the R version from within RStudio.

#### If it does not work...

...revert back to the backup version of the `.profile` using the following command:

```
cp ~/.profile.bak ~/.profile
```

#### If it works...

...you may delete the backup file, or keep it for future reference.

Hope this helps

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! Quick follow up, how can remove the previous version of R that I built from a tarball and is now in /usr/local/bin/R? Should I just have to navigate to the R directory I installed from and run `sudo make uninstall`? I didn't see any uninstall file in there.

Comment: @JJGabe you are welcome! I don't know off-hand how to uninstall something you installed from source, but I think it must have been asked and answered before. Please search the site.

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely).

Comment: That also worked. I'll be sure to use `checkinstall` from now on, though I don't often build source packages. Thanks, again!