# how to uninstall gromacs package via cmake

Tags: uninstall

I have installed gromacs package with deffect to on usr/local/gromacs. Simple command lines like these:
'sudo apt-get remove gromacs,
sudo apt-get remove --purge gromacs,
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gromacs'
did not work.
How to get rid of this package?

Comment: `apt remove` is for packages installed with apt (or dpkg). .... `/usr/local/` is entirely manual installs. .... If you cannot 'make uninstall' from the original gromacs source, then simply remove the files with `sudo rm -r gromacs/`

Comment: See also [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: Thank you Knud Larsen. 'sudo rm -r gromacs/' command line by you has been sufficient