# can't remove a game installed by make install command

Tags: command-line, 20.04, make, makefile

I wanted to install a launcher which is actually for enter and play in a server in Minecraft(I don't know if giving the name of the game is forbidden) and to do this I went to the website of the launcher and downloaded an **.tar.gz** package then I used this command for extract it

`tar -xvf <downloaded.tar.gz>`

It contains an **usr/** folder and a **Makefile** file. Then I used `sudo make install` command for download it and it downloaded successfully(although that, I couldn't launch the game it just crashed) Now I wanna uninstall it but I don't know how to do that I searched for that and visit [some websites](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely) but I didn't work. What I should do?

(Sorry for horrible English)

Comment: Can you, `cd`'d to the directory containing the `Makefile`, do `sudo make uninstall`? Many `Makefile`s provide an '`uninstall`' target.

Comment: @waltinator that didn't work I had deleted Makefile and usr/ , but I extracted again and run sudo make install again and tried "sudo make uninstall" and "sudo make clean" but they both didn't work I always see "No rule to make target uninstall/clean"

Comment: Install the `checkinstall` package, and rerun the install under the control of `logwatch`. That will give you a list of the files installed, that you can manually delete.