# Uninstall an app compiled from source

Tags: compiling, uninstall, source

I've compiled an application from source, so i would appreciate some help on how to reverse the alterations made. Google says that is only a matter of reversing the steps returned by the following command:

```
make -n install
```

Which i already have in a convenient text file. But, my issue is i'm having trouble to understand these commands. Here are the first lines of the text file:

```
for d in libsent libjulius julius mkbingram mkbinhmm adinrec adintool mkgshmm mkss jcontrol gramtools generate-ngram jclient-perl man; do \
  (cd $d; make install); \
done
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pedro/julius/julius-4.3.1/libsent'
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libsent.a /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/include/sent
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/sent/*.h /usr/local/include/sent
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c libsent-config-dist /usr/local/bin/libsent-config
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pedro/julius/julius-4.3.1/libsent'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pedro/julius/julius-4.3.1/libjulius'
```

So if a go to /usr/local/lib for example there is no file (apparently) related to the app itself. But under ~/julius/lib the file libsent.a is there. i don't understand exactly how any substitution taked place in this case, i indeed forced the app to be compiled on ~/julius but the steps returned by make -n install are not making sense to me. Can i just delete the entire ~/julius folder or is not that simple?

Comment: Since you apparently have the Makefile, I'd first check whether it has an `uninstall` target i.e. see what you get if you type `make -n uninstall`

Comment: ... see for example [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/a/87112/178692)

Comment: Perhaps: `cd /home/pedro/julius/julius-4.3.1/libsent` and: `sudo make uninstall` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.